# Update data input with a click

Tags: javascript, jquery

So basically I have a jsp file which has one form and a div. So roughly :

```
<div style="visibility:hidden;" id="popup">
    //several input
</div>
<form>
    //several input
</form>
```

In both the *div* and *form* tag, the fields are the same (but they can have different values). In the form, I have a button which does 2 things :

1. $.getJSON(url) : I set the values for the different input fields
2. document.getElementById('popup').visibility = 'visible'

In the div, I have a button which I'd like to do 2 things :

1. document.getElementById('popup').visibility = 'hidden' : to hide the popup
2. get the values in the div and use those to update the input fields in the form :

   document.getElementById('addressForm').value = document.getElementById('addressPopup').value

//Assuming I have an input for the address with these id's.

In my case I several lines like the one above :

```
function update(){
   document.getElementById('popup').visibility = 'hidden;
   //setting the address
   //setting the name
   //setting the firstname
   //...
}
```

My issue is this one : when I click on the button, the update function is called alright but strangely, only the first line after *document.getElementById('popup').visibility = 'hidden;* is executed (in my example only the address would be updated). Why is that ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you post the entire snippet? preferably, on jsfiddle or something similar

Comment: But since at one point in my code I use $.getJSON(url), wouldn't you be able to run the code even if I put it on jsfiddle ?

Comment: you can have it request https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/

Comment: Ok I'll try that

Comment: @BorisLobanov I found out what was wrong. Check the answer below. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what my issue was : in one of the line I used the wrong id in getElementById and because of that all the lines below the faulty one were not executed.